# Python/PyQt/Qt QMenu QAction syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots, qaction

I have a syntax/understanding problem in an application using Python 3, PyQt5 and Qt5.  I am unsure which of these is causing the problem.

I am charged with porting a GUI application which worked under Windows to Linux, with newer versions of libraries.  I do not have access to the original running under Windows.

In several places I see:

```
menu = QMenu(self)
action = menu.addAction("Some string")
action.triggered[()].connect(self.handler)
```

I presume this used to work.  I am porting to Python 3.5, PyQt 5.7 & Qt 5.7.  I have reason to believe the code was written for earlier versions of each of these.

Executing it now generates a `'there is no matching overloaded signal'` error, on the `action.triggered[()]` segment.

By guesswork and looking at a couple of examples I found somewhere, I have changed the last line to:

```
action.triggered.connect(self.handler)
```

and it seems to work now.

Could someone explain what the original `triggered[()]` syntax meant/worked, and which "product" the evident change was in --- it would be nice to be able to read about where this got changed?  Is my replacement by simply `triggered` correct/same behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant change happened in PyQt-5.3. It is **not** entirely safe to simply remove the old syntax, as this could easily create a subtle bug in both current and future code.

The issue is that certain signals like `triggered` will always send a default boolean value unless you take steps to eliminate it. Qt defines these signals like this:

```
    triggered(bool checked = false)
```

PyQt previously implemented this as two overloads:

```
    triggered(bool checked)
    triggered()
```

and if you wanted to explicitly select the latter overload, you had to use the following slightly awkward sytax:

```
    triggered[()].connect(slot)
```

But this is now no longer an option, as only the first overload is implemented. So to get *exactly* the same behaviour, it is necessary to either wrap the handler like this:

```
    triggered.connect(lambda checked: slot())
```

or decorate it like this:

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handleTriggered(self):
        pass
```

Otherwise, it is quite easy to fall into a little trap. Imagine you have a method defined like this:

```
    def frobnicate(self, foobar=True):
        if foobar:
            # do something nice
        else:
            # empty my home directory without prompting
```

Later on, you decide to hook this up to a button, like this:

```
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.frobnicate)
```

Which all seems perfectly fine, until you find out that the `clicked` signal works just like `triggered`, and always sends `False` by default...

Of course, if you're *absolutely certain* that you will *never* connect slots which take arguments to signals like `triggered` and `clicked`, you could get away with connecting them all in the simplistic fashion shown above. But, really, that is just an accident waiting to happen...

Comment: _This_ is the kind of answer I was hoping for!  Could you please clarify _what_ (syntactically) `triggered[()]` meant? I am new to Python.  Is that "an array of `()`"??

Comment: @JonBrave. A tuple of argument types is used to select the specific overload you want. The `()` is empty tuple, meaning: select the overload with no arguments.

Comment: @JonBrave. I should probably add that signals are custom python objects that implement the [`__getitem__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). They're conceptually more like a `dict` (mapping) than an array - although, to some extent, python's duck-typing allows them to be treated in much the same way.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a document link for PyQt-5.3 which enumerates this behaviour change?  I could do with looking through for other potentials!

Comment: @JonBrave. Try: [Incompatibilities with Earlier Versions](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html) in the [PyQt5 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/index.html).

Comment: Great, though your explanation was a lot clearer :)  Thanks for all help.